# Find path distance between nodes of net?

Tags: ruby, recursion, graph, distance

I am writing a web crawler and I need to find the minimal distance between two URLs.

I'm representing the net with hash. Every node, which is not at the end of the net, is keyed to the vector of the nodes, to which it is connected:

```
hash = {:v0 => [:v1,  :v2,  :v3],
        :v1 => [:v4,  :v5,  :v6], 
        :v2 => [:v7,  :v8,  :v9],
        :v3 => [:v10, :v11, :v12],
        :v4 => [:v13, :v14, :v15]}
```

This solution is not working. The problem is that I only increment the distance (dist variable) when it finds the target, so the result is always `1`:

```
def path src, target, hash, dist
    return -1 if hash[src] == nil # invalid distance if source is invalid
    return dist += 1 if hash[src].include? target

    arr = Array.new
    for i in hash[src] do
        arr.push path(i, target, hash, dist) 
    end
    arr = arr.delete_if {|x| x < 0} # delete invalid values
    return -1 if arr.empty?
    return arr.min # return the shortest distance
end
```

How can I fix it so it will increment on every layer of the net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Here is the code, if it would help to someone.

```
def distance src, target, hash
    return 0 if src == target
    return nil if hash[src].nil?
    dist = 1

    if hash[src].include? target
        return dist
    else
        arr = hash[src].map {|x| distance x, target, hash}
    end
    arr = arr.delete_if {|x| x.nil?}

    return dist + arr.min if !arr.empty?
    return nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not completely understood the idea of recursion. For that, first write down a definition of your "path distance". The reason I quote that is that I would expect you either want the distance or you want the path (where the length of the path is the distance), but I don't really know what you need.

Now, the reason that is important is that in this case it's probably something like "the path is the shortest distance from the current URL to the target URL". The implementation is something like "if the target URL is a direct neighbour, the distance is 1, otherwise it's the shortest distance from any of the neighbours plus 1". In your case, you pass in an existing distance, which is not really wrong but unusual. Following, if you find the URL in `hash[src]`, you increment that distance (is Ruby pass-by-reference, BTW?) *and* return it. At that point, I would actually expect you to return 1, because that is the distance between the current position and the target. Similarly, later on, you probably need to increment `dist`, too, before passing it to the recursive call.

Now, there is a completely different problem, and that is that your algorithm is inefficient to the point that it will become useless with more than a handful of URLs. Let's assume that the URLs are connected like "A - X - T", with X the start, T the target. If you are unlucky, you first descend into A, which might be a cloud of thousands of URLs. Each of these will find a path to T after traversing the whole graph. Take a look at the difference between breadth-first search (BFS) and depth-first search (DFS) which will give you a hint how to fix it.

Two more things:

- Consider the path between A and A. I would say that their distance is zero, which your function should handle. The distance then becomes: If S=T, the distance is zero, otherwise it is one plus the shortest distance to any neighbor.
- I would try to avoid using -1 for "not found". I'd rather return nothing (nil?), because then it's less likely that you are accidentally doing any arithmetic on it.